# How to escape colon and other special characters while creating a cloudant view in javascript

Tags: javascript, escaping, couchdb, view, cloudant

I have a cloudant db with sample documents as shown below -

```
{
    "_id": "xyz",
    "_rev": "1-sdsdsdfsdfsdfsdf",
    "a:b:c:d:1.0": {
        "pqr": {
           "insideattribute": "value"
         }
     }
 }
```

I need to create a view using following logic -

```
function(doc) {
  // insideattribute is not null
  if(doc.a:b:c:d:1.0.pqr.insideattribute) {
     emit(doc._id, doc._rev);
  }
}
```

However the javascript syntax goes invalid due to ":" and "." characters in the if condition. Have tried escaping with double quotes but does seem to work.

Is there some other way to escape this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [Property accessors - Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

```
function(doc) {
  // insideattribute is not null
  if(doc["a:b:c:d:1.0"]["pqr"]["insideattribute"]) {
     emit(doc._id, doc._rev);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access using `doc['a:b:c:d:1.0']` notation.